# What could make Phonon/DirectShow miss a standard codec?

Tags: qt, directshow, phonon

We're developing a Qt-based application that includes video playback using Phonon. We use .avi files with MJPEG compression (as we need fast seeking to particular frames).

On the development machine (running Windows 7) all works well - Phonon uses DirectShow backend, DirectShow loads and plays our video files using standard MJPEG codec from `quartz.dll`.

But some of the testers on Windows 7 reported broken video playback, I had a quick on one of the machines and see nothing special there, but:

- **InstalledCodecs** utility reports MJPEG codec present and enabled
- **Windows Media Player** plays the files fine (but I gather it uses a different backend, not the DirectShow).
- **Media Player Classic** configured to use **DirectShow** and the standard MJPEG plugin complains that there is no codec available.
- Our software indeed breaks, apparently for the same reason, whatever it is.

The phonon backend is installed in the plugins directory which is added to the search paths which I see listed in the logs, so it should be loaded. I renamed QtSDK on the development machine to make sure only installed qt plugins are available to the application and it continues to work there.

I would appreciate any advice as to where to look at next.

What I'd eventually like to know is:

- what could be the problem
- how could installer or the app itself detect the problem
- how could the problem be solved - either automatically, or by instructing the user

Comment: Another codec could take over `JPEG` decoding (or `MJPG` - whatever you are using). You'd be better off having filter graph topology at the time of error, and error code that you should be registering as a result of some API method.

Comment: We wouldn't mind if some other codec took over decoding, as long as it would produce the frames :-) I'll have a look into writing a simple test app just to attempt to build the filter graph and test for any error condition and what not. Thanks for the support ;)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue recently, but it was with a variety of video file formats, not necessarily just the MPEG compression.

The solution I found was to install a coverall codec pack.  This did a good job for the setup on a handful of computers.  If you are deploying to a lot of users, you will probably want to find the exact codecs you need and make sure phonon can find them.

[K-Lite Codec Pack Download](http://codecguide.com/download_kl.htm)

Comment: on the development machine we have no k-lite codecs (or any non-standard) installed and the video plays. as an experiment I actually installed k-lite full pack on the tester's machine and it didn't help. So I guess the problem is some misconfiguration on their machine, it's just I have no idea how to investigate it.

Comment: Qt looks for a few extra dlls at runtime, sometimes.  Use dependency walker, and make it hard for your program to find the install folder of Qt, to see what Dll's it is missing.

Comment: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qcoreapplication.html#libraryPaths Here it mentions that the library paths in Qt searches the install directory of Qt on your developer machine, and so sometimes modules work fine in development, but when deployed, are missing the other dlls... I also read somewhere that Phonon depends on QtOpenGL4.dll sometimes.

Comment: on the dev machine I only have Qt in the QtSDK and while testing I renamed its directory and made the app log `libraryPaths` - when QtSDK is renamed it doesn't even show up in `libraryPaths`, but the video still plays. Hence, I suspect, that the app finds qt plugins where they are installed (next to .exe). That QtOpenGL4 business I'll have to double check...

Comment: Is there an equivalent for OSX? Perian doesn't seem to work for MP4s via Phonon