# QMediaPlayer can't open media files

Tags: c++, qt, video, codec, multimedia

I'm trying to set-up a QVideoWidget in my app, but i get no audio/video. This is how i create the relevant objects:

```
m_player = new QMediaPlayer;

m_playlist = new QMediaPlaylist(m_player);
m_playlist->addMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("/home/username/Documents/test.mp4"));

m_widgetVideo = new QVideoWidget;
m_player->setVideoOutput(m_widgetVideo);

m_layout = new QHBoxLayout(this);
m_layout->addWidget(m_widgetVideo);
this->setLayout(m_layout);

m_playlist->setCurrentIndex(0);
m_player->play();
```

All i get is a black screen and no audio nor video. I don't know if I can post the MP4 file here (It's a test file downloaded from YouTube) so if anyone needs info about it, just ask me and I'll get it. Here is the result of running ffprobe on the test files: http://pastebin.com/xpMYbApY

```
QMediaPlayer->duration();  = -1
QMediaPlayer->supportedMimeTypes(); = ()
QMediaPlayer->errorString() = ""
```

Also, I have these gstreamer packages:

```
gstreamer0.10-alsa
gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
gstreamer0.10-nice
gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad
gstreamer0.10-plugins-bad-multiverse
gstreamer0.10-plugins-base
gstreamer0.10-plugins-base-apps
gstreamer0.10-plugins-good
gstreamer0.10-plugins-ugly
gstreamer0.10-pulseaudio
gstreamer0.10-tools
gstreamer0.10-x
```

gst-launch-0.10 plays the files perfectly, does this means Qt actually can't find the installed GStreamer codecs?

Comment: May be backend plugin is missing for mp4, you should try some AVI or MP3 file first to see if your code works fine

Comment: None of these worked, either.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12584767/what-could-make-phonon-directshow-miss-a-standard-codec/12591898#12591898

Hope that helps.

Comment: It's a cross-plataform app, so I believe I can't rely on codec packs for Windows. (I have libav on my test machine)

Comment: So I guess you can either include codecs for each platform you are targeting, or you could use libraries like VLC for decoding nearly anything, or you could restrict your player to codecs that are already included on the machine.  FFMPEG also has libraries made for mp4.

Comment: Qt says it uses Gstreamer on linux, but i have all the needed gst-codecs and still can't play the file in my app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem was the QMediaPlaylist. For some reason, it wasn't working. All I had to do to fix it was:

```
m_player->setMedia(QUrl::fromLocalFile("path/to/file"));
```

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a old problem, but 2 years later, I have encountered the same problem. Since I dont have enough rep points to leave a comment, I am posting this as an answer.

This worked for me:

```
playlist = new QMediaPlaylist;
playlist->addMedia(QUrl("http://example.com/movie1.mp4"));
playlist->addMedia(QUrl("http://example.com/movie2.mp4"));
playlist->addMedia(QUrl("http://example.com/movie3.mp4"));
playlist->setCurrentIndex(1);

player = new QMediaPlayer;
player->setPlaylist(playlist);

videoWidget = new QVideoWidget;
player->setVideoOutput(videoWidget);
videoWidget->show();

player->play();
```

Taken right from [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmediaplaylist.html)

As for the why part in @wingleader's answer, I am guessing

```
m_playlist = new QMediaPlaylist(m_player);
```

was logically parenting the playlist to the player but not setting the `m_player`'s playlist property.

HTH